# Symfony fixture & many to many relationship (Doctrine)

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I am trying to create fixtures on a table that has a many to many relationship, but I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bambinbazar`.`bambinbazar_category_articles`, CONSTRAINT `babi` FOREIGN KEY (`articles_id`) REFERENCES `bambinbazar_articles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

In my fixture :

```
BambinbazarArticles:  
 article_vetement:
  title:          bla bla
  BambinbazarCategory: [whateverCat]
```

In my schema:

```
relations:
  BambinbazarCategory: 
    class:BambinbazarCategory
    refClass: BambinbazarCategoryArticles
    local: category_id
    foreign: articles_id
    foreignAlias:  BambinbazarArticles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the fixtures in such an order that doesn't try to create a "child" record before a "parent" record for it exists in the database. When you load all the fixtures at once, it's creating illegal foreign-key referenced fields so it throws that error.

Maybe there's some clever way around it but I personally just load the fixtures separately, starting from the parent, by taking the fixture files out of the fixtures folder, running the standard load-data command, sticking the other fixture file back in, and repeating the command.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a BambinbazarCategory object with a fixture first (whatevercat does not reference anything, does it?)